# Error in design

Tags: discussion, bug

Today morning I found there is a design issue near `Next privilege`

in user activity tab

[image]

Comment: can you still reproduce this? Can you try on a different browser?

Comment: @Marius able to reproduce in different browser as well as in incognito mode

Comment: @Marius link for your reference https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/29731/murtuza-zabuawala?tab=topactivity

Comment: summoning @Hynes

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: @AmitBera its not fixed yet

Comment: Issue is fixed now :)